# MS ACCESS how to average 3 columns in 2 tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following tables:

```
T1:
Repair_ID, Descreption,Cost,Level
(1,a,24,9)
(2,b,34,9)
(3,a,22,3)
(4,c,11,6)

T2:
Repair_ID, Start_Time, End_Time,Location_ID
(1,02:00:00,03:00:00,3)
(2,04:00:00,05:00:00,7)
(3,06:00:00,08:00:00,3)
```

I want to be able to get a table that contains an average of the cost, an average of the level, and an average of the duration of the repair(by subtracting end_Time from start_time) grouping by Descreption and Location_ID 
so the table would look like this:
Descreption, Location_ID, AvgCost,AvgLevel, Avg Duration
(a,3,(24+22/2)=24,(9+3/2=6), 01:30:00*)

- 1 hour for repair_ID 1 and 2 hours for repair_ID 3 = 01:30:00 on average since these two repairs happened in the same location and have the same descreption
  thank you

Comment: What have you already tried so far? What sql statement did you have so far?

Comment: SELECT T1.Description, AVG(T1.Level), AVG (T1.Cost), T3.Location FROM T1, T2,3 WHERE T1.Repair_ID=T2.Repair_ID AND T2.Repair_ID=T£.Repair_ID GROUP BY T1.Descreption, T3.Location ORDER BY AVG(T1.Level), AVG (T1.Cost); still doesnt work

Comment: You can edit your question to include what you've tried and why it doesn't work (e.g. "it gave an error", "the output looks like x but I want y")

Answer (score 2):

This actually pretty straight forward. Join the three tables and do the calculations and grouping you've described

**Update** Formatting an average of Difference of dates is a little tricky. You need to do the format after the Aggregate has been performed. The easiest way to do this is to use an in line view

```
SELECT 
     Descreption,
     Location_id,
     AvgLevel,
     AvgCost,
     Format(CDATE(AvgDuration),"hh:mm:ss") AvgDuration
FROM
(
    SELECT
        repair.Descreption,
        location.Location_id,
        AVG(repair.level) AvgLevel,
        AVG(repair.Cost) AvgCost,
        AVG(times.end_time - times.start_time)  AvgDuration 

    FROM 
        T3 location
        INNER JOIN t1 repair
        on location.repair_id = repair.repair_id
        INNER JOIN t2 times
        ON location.repair_id = times.repair_id
    GROUP BY
        repair.Descreption,
        location.Location_id) foo
ORDER BY
       AvgCost desc
```

Comment: it says data mismatch in critirea expression

Comment: Is you repair_id the same type in all three tables?

Comment: it all works okay now except for the average of time : i tried using this one: AVG(Format((T2.EndTime_time) - (T2.Start_Time),"hh:nn:ss")) but still doesnt work

Comment: DateDiff works except that i want the format of the duration to be Hours:Minutes:Seconds how can i do that?

Comment: @Tantoon Ok I updated my answer, NOTE I'm no longer using DateDiff

Comment: i didnt get this (format after the Aggregate has been performed.).. so it has to be two queries ?

Comment: @Tantoon Its one query. It just also has a subquery. This typically won't affect performance much because the engine can optimize this.

Comment: the question has beem updated to include 2 tables instead of 3